# How to import specific fields from objects from a JSON file to MYSQL 8.0

Tags: mysql

With MySql 8 you can import `json` data directly with `jsondata` flag with the `--import` command. This is the official link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-json-import-command.html 
But how do you import specific fields in the json data to specific column of an already defined table.
For eg: If you have a `countries` table with (id, code, name) and a json file with structure like

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  code: "foo",
  name: "bar",
  otherField1: "baz",
  otherField2: "baz2" 
 },
 {
  ...
 }
]
```

Comment: I don't think shell utilities can be used to transform JSON documents into MySQL table data. The examples given are used to move multiple JSON into a _single_ column of JSON type.

Comment: while you can use it to import data into a table https://mysqlserverteam.com/import-json-to-mysql-made-easy-with-the-mysql-shell/ you can't select them, yo try it with oho or python perl, c# vb net .....

Answer (score 1):

Do it in 2 steps. First you import the JSON file into a staging table. Then you insert into your final table from the staging table

Something like

```
create table country_staging json_text VARCHAR(1000);

mysqlsh user@localhost:33062 --import /jsonpath/countries.json countries_staging jsondata --schema=mydb


INSERT INTO countries (id, code, name, otherfield1, otherfield2)
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, "$.id"), 
       JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, "$.code"),
       JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, "$.name"),
       JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, "$.otherfield1"),
       JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, "$.otherfield2")
FROM countries_staging
```

Comment: Upvoted, but I'd suggest using JSON_TABLE() since the JSON the OP is importing is an array. I would  guess they want it imported into multiple rows, one row per array element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think my data can fit in a singel `varchar` field. Plus, as Bill Karwin pointed out, it is an array of json object, and it can be huge for eg for cities. I looked into JSON_TABLE() but can't seem to figure out exactly how to implement it. Maybe one of you can elaborate furthur. Thanks.